# Python Regular Expression for pattern containing multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract all the text printed after "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"

```
Give me some text!
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA




        S
       p
      p
     p
Epppp
```

The following does not work:

```
import re

m = re.findall(r'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA(.*)', result)

print m[0]
```

Also, can I specify a variable in a regular expression instead of a hard coded string: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"?

Reason being, the text: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" is a variable and changes. So, I would like to look for a specific variable value in the pattern and then extract all the text after it.

Comment: Specify flag `re.DOTALL`. You can build your regular expression by concatenating string (variable)s together. Have a look at `re.escape` to avoid accidental metahcaracters in the string variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` (they are synonyms) to have `findall` match across lines. Or, in your case, `search` is probably more appropriate since you only want one match. Also, to have it work for a non-hard-coded string, simply use string formatting or string concatenation. To avoid having unescaped regex characters in the string, run it through `re.escape`.

```
import re

result = """Give me some text!
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA




        S
       p
      p
     p
Epppp"""

s = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
# With formatting
m = re.search(r'{}(.*)'.format(re.escape(s)), result, re.S)
# With concatenation
m = re.search(re.escape(s) + r'(.*)', result, re.S)

print m.group(1)
```